# FMOD and simple If statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, if-statement, fmod

I have a simple set of FMOD actions that each play various sounds separately. The problem comes in that I have a button that stops all the sounds. FMOD crashes my program if we try to stop a sound that isn't playing.  Makes sense. But I've decided that there has to be a way to call a simple if statement to find out "if" and only "if" somethings playing, then stop it.

```
- (IBAction)myButton:(id)sender {


    if "FMOD CHANNEL IS PLAYING" {

        result = fmodChannel->stop();

    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that `fmodChannel` is going POOF! on you when the playing stops, because it's not retained.

Comment: Everything works as it should and I'm retaining it in previous code. The problem arises when I try to stop a non-playing sound. So this IBAction is a "Back to Main Menu" button and I want to set the channel to stop only "if" its playing. I suppose my question is more, how does FMOD do if statements and is there a way to find out what channels are playing and if so stop them?

Comment: Maybe the crash report will bring the light here.

Comment: Yes, the traceback should show you where the error is actually occurring and give a hint as to its cause.  You should post it here.

Comment: (I think there is some other cause for your error other than the sound simply being done playing.  What specific error are you getting?)

Comment: -1 for not posting the traceback and error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say it “makes sense” that FMOD crashes if you call `stop` on a channel that isn't playing.  It's documented to return an error code on failure.  Are you sure `fmodChannel` is still a valid pointer when you call `stop`?

Anyway, you can try the `isPlaying` method:

```
bool isPlaying;
if (fmodChannel->isPlaying(&isPlaying) == FMOD_OK && isPlaying) {
    fmodChannel->stop();
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Is there any way FMOD allows us to use multiple channels in this? Perhaps like - bool isPlaying;
if (fmodChannel1,fmodChannel2,fmodChannel3->isPlaying(&isPlaying) == FMOD_OK && isPlaying) {
    fmodChannel1,fmodChannel2,fmodChannel3->stop();
}

Comment: Hey @RobMayoff do you by chance have any ideas on the DSP front? looking to solve this too! Let me know man! I'd love the help brother! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375347/fmod-stop-or-reset-a-dsp

Comment: @SeanHerman I have never used FMOD or a DSP.  I simply looked at the FMOD documentation to answer this question.