# FMOD Stop or Reset a DSP?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, fmod

I have a question about stopping DSP's in FMOD. I have a button that I want to stop my DSP from being enabled.

```
- (IBAction)myButton:(id)sender {

   FMOD_DSP_Reset(FMOD_DSP_TYPE_ECHO *myEcho);

}
```

Any ideas? I've looked into the documentation - but it's not working for me. Any help would he highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! I figured it out - it was simple. I think I was over complicating it.

All I needed to do was throw in the simple remove call into the action. :)

```
result = myEcho->remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also DSP::setActive or DSP::setBypass